# ng-select won't recognise the ng-model is a valid option and should be selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an angular app that contains a form, which has a select. I can choose one of the selects, and its updated in the model perfectly. But the next time i go in the form its suppose to be "pre filled" as the data already exists. And all the data is filled ok, but angular doesn't seem to recognise that the value of the model corresponds to the value of the select.

html/angular:

```
<select ng-model="userData.country" 
        ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries">
</select>
```

data

```
[
  {"iso":"DK","name":"Danmark"},
  {"iso":"DE","name":"Germany"}
]
```

The wanted behaviour is that once I set this data to userData.country, that the form will come pre-selected with the correct country that the user chose in the previous form.

Comment: How are you pre-filling your form?

Comment: Just bounding the input fields with an ng-model to something that has data

Comment: It would be easier if you provided a plunker showing where the binding does not work.

Comment: I am new to javascript, will use plunker from now on. Thank you for the positive comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your HTML you need to add country.iso instead of country

```
<select ng-model="userData.country" 
     ng-options="country.iso as country.name for country in countries">
</select>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.userData = {"country":"DK"}; // this can be filled with prefilled data. which can be fetched from db or stored in a service
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was asking, because if I use objects it's still unrecognised, however, this is exactly what I was looking for. I don't actually need to save the entire object in my user details, just the iso code. So, I guess you know me better than me :)

Comment: or actually you can add
`$scope.userData={};
$scope.userData.country="DK";`

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to save the whole object instead of just the iso code here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ES4t/

JS File:

```
$scope.countries = [{
  iso: "DK",
  name: "Danmark"
}, {
  iso: "DE",
  name: "Germany"
}];
$scope.userData = {};
$scope.userData.country = $scope.countries[0];
```

HTML File:

```
<select ng-model="userData.country" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries"></select>
```

I would suggest storing the whole object, that you wouldn't have to search the country array later if you needed the name and only had the ISO code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not filling the form in the *Angular Way*.

To do this, you should set the model (and the form will be pre-filled):

In your controller:

```
$scope.countries = [
  {"iso":"DK","name":"Danmark"},
  {"iso":"DE","name":"Germany"},
  {"iso":"PT","name":"Portugal"},
  {"iso":"CN","name":"Canada"}
];

$scope.userData = {};
$scope.userData.country = $scope.countries[3];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5118/)

Comment: My flow of events is: 1.The user gets an empty form he fills out 2.the user can go into an edit form that is filled out with the info he has put in. The way I fill out the form is just by "binding" to the same variables as the other form set in, so I can imagine why there would be a discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your html/angular to

```
<select ng-model="country" 
     ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-change="countryChanged(country)">
</select>
```

and your controller:

```
$scope.countryChanged = function(country){
    $scope.userData.country = country
}
```